# The best chromatographic technique to analyse a solution of benzene, toluene, and ethylbenzene in n-hexane

Tags: organic-chemistry, analytical-chemistry, hydrocarbons, chromatography

> What is the best chromatographic technique to analyse a solution containing benzene, toluene, and ethylbenzene in *n*-hexane?

Is gas chromatography (GC) the best way to analyse this solution? Or is using liquid chromatography with a non polar eluent and column better than GC in this case?

Comment: Seems tailormade for GC with flame ionisation

Comment: Define better :-)

Comment: What you want to analyze? to separate? percentage of a mixture? or anything else? You need to elaborate a little more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best is relative. Fastest and easiest would be a direct GC liquid injection. That run would be less than 10 minutes on a 624 column or other non-polar column. HPLC is much more complicated than GC with the different mobile phases and solvents.

Answer (score 1):

The choice of analytical technique is based on three simple factors: what is available, and how low concentration do you want to go, and how much *time* do you have? Do you have a gas chromatograph with flame ionization detector or a UV high performance liquid chromatograph or both? This type of mixture is readily amenable to both GC and reversed phase HPLC. The only problem is hexane in reversed phase HPLC, but if less than 1 uL is injected it should be fine.